# Java String comparision

Tags: java, android, string

I am facing strange issue i am getting string from database and comparing with a string, but when i compare them with equals operator they do not come equal.

String1 =  Love is a game that two can play and both win.
String2 =  Love is a game that two can play and both win.

```
         Cursor data = database2.query("Quote", fields,  null, null, null, null, null);
         data.moveToFirst();


         for(int i = 0; i < data.getCount() ; i++){
         if(data.getString(2).trim().equals(_qt2.trim())){
              Log.i("Found Matching quote", "");
              data.moveToPosition(i);
          }  
      }
```

This is the log:

```
    E/Data 2(8818): Love is a game that two can play and both win.
    E/Data 3(8818): Love is a game that two can play and both win.
```

Thanks

Comment: Try to use data.getString(2).trim().equals(_qt2.trim())

Comment: could you show some more code? And maybe you could Log the strings, so that you're sure they are completely equal.

Comment: if data.getString(2) and _qt2 have the same content, the if will return true. you need to show more code, e.g. the table and the query, as well as the declaration/definition of _qt2.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but that log output you show could not have possibly come from your code snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use trim(), ignorecase and contains (if your scenario supports it)

Answer (score 2):

```
 if(data.getString(2).trim().equals(_qt2.trim())){
              Log.i("Found Matching quote", "");
          }
```

I assume data.getString(2) is contain String1 and _qt2 contains String2 as described in your question. Also I recomonded you to first check with

```
System.out.println(data.getString(2));
```

and

```
System.out.println(_qt2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the strings don't contain what you think they do. Print out the contents of each, to make sure. See the other answers for guidance on trimming whitespace, etc.

Or, maybe you aren't seeing the expected log output because you've put the Log message in the Tag parameter, rather than the Message parameter. Try this instead.

```
Log.i("My App", "Found matching quote");
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert both String into byte[] (or char[]), 
then compare every element in them. 
Maybe you will be able to see the difference.